# ¿Cómo sumar/restar un día a la fecha actual en Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
var currentDate = new Date();

/* Construye un arreglo para obtener el nombre de los meses */

var month     = new Array();
    month[0]  = "ENERO";
    month[1]  = "FEBRERO";
    month[2]  = "MARZO";
    month[3]  = "ABRIL";
    month[4]  = "MAYO";
    month[5]  = "JUNIO";
    month[6]  = "JULIO";
    month[7]  = "AGOSTO";
    month[8]  = "SEPTIEMBRE";
    month[9]  = "OCTUBRE";
    month[10] = "NOVIEMBRE";
    month[11] = "DICIEMBRE";

var nameMonth = month[currentDate.getMonth()];
var month     = currentDate.getMonth();
var day       = currentDate.getUTCDate();



 /* Define la variable "today" con el día y el mes actual */
    var today     = day + "/" + nameMonth;
    Logger.log(today);

    /* Define la variable "tomorrow" que sumará un día a la fecha actual */
    var tomorrow  = (day + 1) + "/" + nameMonth;
    Logger.log(tomorrow);

    /* Define la variable "yesterday" que restará un día a la fecha actual */
    var yesterday = (day - 1) + "/" + nameMonth;
    Logger.log(yesterday);
```

¿Como hago para sumar o restar un día a la fecha actual?

si por ejemplo la fecha actual es "30/NOVIEMBRE" y le sumo un día me da "31/NOVIEMBRE" y así sucesivamente, necesito validar los meses que tienen 30 ó 31 días e igual febrero que cambia cada 4 años a 29 días.

¿Cómo lo realizo en GAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Una de tantas formas es combinar las funciones [getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) y [setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) de la clase Date con el operador adición +, todos de JavaScript. Ejemplo:

```
function demo(){
  var fecha = new Date();
  var otraFecha = fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 1);
  Logger.log(new Date(otraFecha))
}
```

## Explicación

Google Apps Script está basado en JavaScript 1.6 con algunas adiciones de 1.7 y 1.8.

getDate devuelve el día del mes de la fecha especificada y setDate establece la fecha a partir de la fecha actual.

- `fecha.getDate() + 1` devuelve el día siguiente de la fecha indicada.
- `fecha.setDate(...)` devuelve el número de milisegundos que representa la fecha indicada como parámetro.
- `new Date(...)` devuelve un objeto de fecha.
- `Logger.log(...)` imprime su parámetro en los registros del editor de Google Apps Script.